# Twilio status - Using API call

Tags: twilio

I am looking for a solution to monitor Twilio status using API.
my action: Sending an API request from third party monitoring vendor to Twilio status page.
If the API fails (not getting 200 OK), it will mean that there is an issue with Twilio.
Otherwise, all good.

I have found this API call for Twilio status - https://status.twilio.com/api/v2/status.json

I am looking for more "automatically" way to check Twilio way rather than querying this API and checking the status inside the API response.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

At the top of the [Twilio Status page](https://status.twilio.com/#) you will find a button to "Subscribe to updates". Clicking that button will get you options to subscribe to updates. You can subscribe via email, SMS, RSS feed or webhook. If you pick the webhook option, you can opt to have Twilio status updates sent to your application via HTTP request.

However, the status of the Twilio API is not as simple as whether the API is available or not. As I write this answer, the status page describes the service as degraded, but the incidents relate to SMS delivery delays to Somalia Telesom Network, planned carrier maintenance by Bouygues Telecom in France and delays to SMS, MMS and WhatsApp pricing info updates. None of these will stop you from using the Twilio API to send an SMS message (though some of those messages may be delayed in France/Somalia).

I honestly don't recommend that you implement a health check request from a monitoring service as it simply does not tell the whole story. Instead, I would recommend you observe the success rates of your activity with the API and monitor and alert based on error messages received as you try to make requests to the APIs that matter to you and your application's features. You can then bolster this with information delivered to you by subscribing to the [Twilio Status alerts](https://status.twilio.com/#) allowing you to understand whether the API is down, whether a carrier is performing maintenance of if there is some other problem entirely.